# Onde fica "Plugin Manager" do NotePad++?

Tags: notepad++

Acabei de instalar o Notepad++ (64Bits) e me parece que esta com algo errado, pois o item "plugin manager" não aparece?

No google não achei qualquer referencia sobre isso, apenas indicações de instalar plugins, justamente indo nesta opção,}

**veja um print da minha tela:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infelizmente não consegui fazer a **versão de 64bits** funcionar com os plugins. (Sera que ela esta com problemas no original?)

Então estou usando a de **32bits** mesmo, que funciona sem erros e sem perda de velocidade, pelo menos ate onde eu testei.
OU ate que alguém possa me aconselhar sobre outras opções.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não precisei fazer qualquer ajuste, apenas instalei e tudo estava pronto. Inclusive ja ate coloquei os pluguis que preciso.

Eu realmente uso o notepad++ para programar. Ele tem que estar afiado.

Comment: https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases

Answer (score 9):

Baixe o arquivo .zip dessa página -> https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppluginmgr/

Ao descompactar, você irá encontrar duas pastas: **plugins** e **updater**.

Para instalar, copie o arquivo .dll da pasta **plugins** para

C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins (se você tem um SO 64bit)

C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins (se você tem um SO 32bit)

caso não funcione, tente esse outro -> http://www.brotherstone.co.uk/npp/pm/PluginManager_1.0.2_UNI.zip e faça a instalação da mesma forma.

Comment: Ola @Italo Rodrigo, ja fiz, mas **nao deu qualquer efeito**   (nem erro), meu notepad e um 64bits, (assim com o windows)

Comment: você já reiniciou o notepad++ pra testar?

Comment: Ah sim!  inclusive, o micro também, pra garantir... mas....

Comment: postei outro link, dá uma olhada. caso você saiba inglês, pode ver o link do desenvolvedor aqui -> http://npppluginmgr.sourceforge.net/#install

Comment: nesse link que postei acima, diz que não é obrigado copiar os dois arquivos, basta copiar o .dll pra pasta plugins e depois de instalado, você pode abrir o próprio plugin manager e instalar ele mesmo de forma completa.

Comment: testei...  estranho, não funcionou...   então baixei a versão de 32Bits do notepad++, apaguei todos os vestígios dele nas pastas, e re-instalei...  funfou..

Comment: Sera um defeito da versao 64bits?

Comment: não dá pra saber. talvez não exista o plugin pra 64bit. como eu uso o de 32bit, nunca tive esse problema

Comment: Isso não funciona para a versão de 64bits

Answer (score 3):

Tive o mesmo problema e a solução que encontrei foi desinstalar o **Notepad++** e
instalar a versão **7.3 32 bit X86**.

A versão 64 bits não carrega o *plugin manager*. Na versão **7.3**, já aparece nas opções o quadro *plugin manager*, que não aparece nas versões mais recentes.

Desta forma, depois de instalado, você poderá atualizar o programa, sem perder o menu.

Answer (score 2):

Para instalação do Plugin Manager no Notepad++ x64 (v7.5.1):

- Baixe a variante x64 do Plugin Manager aqui: https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases (última versão do arquivo *PluginManager_vX.X.X_x64.zip*);
- Extraia o conteúdo do zip em: C:\Program Files\Notepad++ (há duas pastas, cada uma com um arquivo, precisa ser usuário administrador);
- Reinicie o Notepad++.

Fonte: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/13661/plugin-manager-x64-available-submit-your-plugins